# The correct way to parse "就打赢了" in 是个很普通就打赢了的对手哦?

Tags: meaning, syntax

I was reading an excerpt from a story, and I'm having a discussion with my friend over the correct way to parse this line said by a certain character, let's call him 1, about character 2.

> 是个很普通就打赢了的对手哦

2 overhears this and reacts angrily.

The difficulty stems from the target of 打赢了.

I believe the line would translate to something like this:

> It was very common to win against this opponent.

My friend tells me it's more like:

> It's very common for this opponent to win.

But if character 2 reacts angrily, isn't that a provocation? Which would mean mine makes sense in the context.
Any help with understanding the correct parsing will be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

> "是个很普通就打赢了的" is an adjectival phrase for "对手"

是 - is (verb)

个 - a (classifier for the noun 对手)

很普通**就** (**just** easily) 打赢了(defeated)

的 (adjectival phrase marker)

对手- opponent [noun]

> 就 here means "**just**"
>
> "打赢了的对手" = "defeated opponent"
>
> "是个很普通(就)打赢了的对手" = "is (just) an easily defeated opponent"

*'普通就' is short for '普通地打**就**' (**just** fight normally)*

Other example of '就' functions as 'just':

一美元(就)卖了 = sold (just) for one dollar

Answer (score 2):

> 是个很普通就打赢了的对手哦

Tang Ho's analysis is correct. Semantically, the sentence is saying "*One is such an opponent or contestant that can be defeated by normal playing (versus playing hard)*". Put it another way: "*I don't have to play hard to defeat him.*".

It is indeed a provocation if you say that in front of your contestants or their supporters. So, your analysis is more correct than your friend's.